# Type mismatch error on importing values to an array

Tags: excel, vba

I m initializing an array and import values from a specific range. if the range are greater than one line the code works fine BUT in case the range is just one line i m getting an error of:

> Run time error 13: Type mismatch

**Code:**

```
Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        arr = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Any help will appreciated.

After @JvdV answer i manage to overcome this problem but i face other one:

when there is more than one lines the array looks like that:

[image]

But when there is only one line:

[image]

How to create the same array structure - dimensions?

Comment: That's because it's not an array with just a line. Build in a check for last row and if just one line, redim the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a single cell you won't have an array. Turn on local variables to check this behaviour.

What you can do for example is to check if arr actually is an array or check the value of `LastRow`. For example:

```
Sub test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long, lr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Range("A1:A" & lr)

    If lr = 1 Then ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1): arr(1,1) = .Cells(1, 1)

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i,1)
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i manage to find the solution from your comment. thanks for your time! is there a way to redim the array ans start from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Could you please take a look to the edited question because it is seems that i missing something because i dont manage to get the same array structure?

Comment: Shall i use `ReDim arrChampions(1 To 1, 1 To 1)`